# Ошибка expected string , помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, обработка-ошибок

```
import re

input_filename = "../progr.txt"
result_filename = "../result.txt"

input_file = open(input_filename, mode = 'r', encoding='Latin-1')
resultfile = open(result_filename, mode = 'w', encoding='Latin-1')
mytext = input_file.read()

lookfor = r"[\w,-]+@[A-Za-z-]+\.[\w.]+"

mytext = input_file.read
results = re.findall(lookfor, mytext)

for item in results:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Добавьте код самой ошибки.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/markh/Desktop/bot/pr.py", line 13, in <module>
    results = re.findall(lookfor, mytext)
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Видите тут разницу `mytext = input_file.read()` и `mytext = input_file.read`? Во втором случае вы не вызываете функцию и в переменной будет ссылка на функцию

Comment: все равно ошибка(

Comment: @Maina, просто уберите `mytext = input_file.read`, вы ведь уже ранее считали все из файла (а заново считывать не нужно и не имеет смысла). Кст, пишите ник с @, чтобы уведомление о комментарии было мне отображено :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь считать данные из одного и того же файла дважды. Так не работает, в первый раз считали все данные – последующие считывания будут выдавать пустой результат.

Как я понял, вы пытаетесь получить email'ы из файла с помощью регулярки. Если убрать из кода дублирующую строчку

```
mytext = input_file.read  # <--- убрать вот эту строку
results = re.findall(lookfor, mytext)
```

то все должно запуститься

По крайней мере с примером

```
max@mail.ru
hello@google.com
asdlkasdasd
```

отрабатывает без проблем.